# How do I make an MLT request in SOLR for a document that is in another core?

Tags: solr

/solr/col1/ - the core where the my_doc document is located

/solr/col2/ - MLT is needed here for my_doc id

The only option that comes to mind is to create a copy of the document from another collection in the current one and execute the MLT query. But this is not a good option...

Comment: If you use the MoreLikeThisHandler you can query for the document from core 1, then supply the text as the body of the request to core 2 - the content included as a POST body is what will be used for the similarity matching in core 2. That way you don't have to copy the content or do anything magic, and the document you're searching for similarities to can come from any source. https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/morelikethis.html#streaming-external-content-to-morelikethis https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/morelikethishandler